# Android Building on Arch Linux 64-bit: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, archlinux

So I have been getting this error whenever building android projects in Eclipse:

```
[ThisAppBlabla] /home/user/android-sdks/build-tools/19.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Running: Arch Linx 64-bit, Eclipse 4.3.1, Android for Eclipse plugin.

Locate libz.so.1 outputs:

```
/usr/lib/libz.so.1
/usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.8
```

I have searched through some similar posts on forums,  but so far no luck.  Thanks!

Comment: could you post snapshot of sdk manager ?

Answer (score 6):

Ok, actually dug through some more packages, and it ends up I needed to install ["lib32-zlib "](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/multilib/x86_64/lib32-zlib/).  Well, maybe that will help someone else out in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ran into the same issue. I installed the 64-bit android sdk on Suse, but needed the 32-bit versions of libz and libstdc++ before my build would run.